# C# Networking Program

Tags: c#

I am totally new to using C# for networking purposes, can anyone show me in an easy way how to create in a few lines a console application that reads the IP information (Packets)..."Sniffer", i dont need a class or anything.. just in the main program 2 or three lines that would give me this information.

Thank you guys

Comment: You are not going to get the answer just like that for free! Try googling it first, please!!!

Comment: I tried, but it is a bit confusing on what I saw. Basically, I just want to be able to get the IP information in the console...
If anyone cant help its ok thanks

Comment: Hmmm, in that case. @Rerun has provided a good link then. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx

Comment: By the way, if at some point in time, if you dive in to a lower level of network programming, you could try out the very popular Pcap.net at http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do in a two or three line C# program.  You need to replace the winsock driver in the operating system itself so that the operating system will show you packets intended for others, and you can't put managed code into the kernel like that.  This is why software like Wireshark usually also requires you to install [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/).  That said, after winpcap is installed on a system C# can control it and use it to capture packets.